# Choosing a test platform for .NET - MbUnit or the one by Microsoft?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, mbunit

I have chosen these two as primary candidates. My thinking goes like this:

- MbUnit has had a nice start and enjoys a smart, dedicated team of developers.
- MSFT has many resources and can compete with MbUnit easily if they choose to do so.

Which one do you believe I should bet on?

Comment: Well MbUnit.com is down, so I'd say thats your answer.

Comment: That is because they have migrated to another domain, Tovarisch.

Comment: Personally I've gone with MSFT in combination with MOQ, no complaints so far.

Comment: What domain? I went to their google site and both of the links on the site are broken.

Comment: Do some research on how easy it is to migrate from your choice to the prevalent unit testing frameworks.. if it is easy it means your current decision is reversible. Hence it doesn't matter if you make the wrong choice now.. so choose it and move on. IMHO I've found unit testing adequate,  when someone comes up to me saying that NUnit (or any simple UT fwk) is missing some feature, usually the problem is the way in which they've designed the test in their heads. You can restructure to a simpler way & you find NUnit can in fact do it.

Comment: what is with the backwards text? Bad form. Especially putting it back in, after a tidy up.

Comment: *sigh*  The site is back up now.

It looks like the VM that runs the website went down hard due to a power outage earlier this morning and hung during the subsequent restart.

Sorry about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUnit vs. MbUnit vs. MSTest vs. xUnit.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit is more widespread, MbUnit has the most features, but MSTest has more manpower behind it. Check this question out:  [NUnit vs. MbUnit vs. MSTest vs. xUnit.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net)

Answer (score 3):

I love MbUnit because it supports parametrized tests through attributes. So you can do something like this:

```
[Test]
[Row(2,1,2)]
[Row(4,3,1)]
[Row(ExpectedException(typeof(DivideByZeroException)))]
void TestIntDivision(int numerator, int denominator, int result)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(result, numerator/denominator);
}
```

Comment: I like! Whatever happened to their servers though?

Comment: It's fixed.  Just a power outage and a misbehaving VM.

Comment: NUnit now has the same thing with their TestCase attribute in version 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft unit testing framework is kind of tied to Visual Studio. This is both an advantage and disadvantage. Advantage is you can run tests easily from Visual Studio out of the box, disadvantage is forget about Mono support. It's worth noting that VS2010 will support 3rd party unit test frameworks.

Comment: VS 2008 already supports 3rd party unit test frameworks to a degree.  Gallio provides Visual Studio integration for MbUnit, NUnit, xUnit.net and others...