# xUnit or NUnit? What advantages and disadvantages of each other?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, xunit

What are the pluses and minuses of each framework, comparing to each other?
How well they work with ASP.NET MVC?
How well they support mocking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net

Answer (score 26):

I work with NUnit only. It is pretty good for me. It is integrated into different add-ons for Visual Studio like Resharper, it supports in TeamCity and it has stand-alone test launcher

And looks like NUnit become an industry standard for unit testing.

And we haven't had any major issues with [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [Rhino.Mock](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx).

As I remember Asp.Net MVC (I worked with 1.0 only) uses MS Unit. You may easily switch from MSUnit to NUnit.

A similar question was asked already, maybe you find some details here:
[NUnit vs. MbUnit vs. MSTest vs. xUnit.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net)

Comment: Just had a very brief Foray myself into xUnit.  It doesn't support trace output (by design apparently).  No Console.Write.. no Trace/Debug.Write. So you can basically test your code but you can't work out why it failed.  Pretty big flaw if you ask me.  Even for developing a new feature a quick unit test with some output for sanity is vital... So back to Nunit I go.  That was a nice 5 minutes on the other side https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/173?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Comment: ReSharper 2016.1 provides built-in support for xUnit.net and doesn’t require a separate extension to be installed anymore. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/04/14/resharper-ultimate-2016-1-is-released/

Answer (score 15):

An old post, but thought [this](http://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html) would be helpful to someone.

Comment: this post is old so do not used to compare the frameworks, the last edit was Nov 14, 2012. There is more helpers for each framework so go to the official sites and make your decision base on that information

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Magnilex
And it has. It was moved so the link is no longer valid.....

Comment: quite old, the link is dead.