# nunit vs unit test framework built-in with visual studio

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5

Anyone can give a comparison over those two frameworks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUnit vs. MbUnit vs. MSTest vs. xUnit.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couples comparaison out there.

- [MSTest vs. NUnit with Visual Studio 2010 & TDD](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/mstest-vs-nunit-with-visual-studio-2010-tdd/)
- [NUnit vs. MbUnit vs. MSTest vs. xUnit.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net)
- [NUnit vs. MsTest: NUnit wins for Unit Testing](http://www.osherove.com/blog/2010/3/5/nunit-vs-mstest-nunit-wins-for-unit-testing.html)