# How to start functional testing by using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, junit

I have to write own test framework in Visual Studio 2008 by using C# in order to perform functional test of a new Windows Appl.

If it was Eclipse IDE I would use JUnit as a base class and expand its functionality by adding  new classes with its own methods related on the Windows API.

How can I get started in case of Visual Studio? Does it have any similar to junit build-in packages in its environment?

BR,

Irina.

Comment: if you're familiar with JUnit, I'd stick to NUnit over (the builtin) MSTest

Answer (score 3):

MSTest is the primary built-in testing framework for Visual Studio. However, there is also a plug-in for Visual Studio called [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/) that will allow you to run tests for NUnit, MBUnit or MSTest. It is free for academic use, open source developers, and trial.

You may also want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net) comparing a few of the .NET unit test framework options.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2008 does have a build in unit test mechanism you could utilize in this manner or you could use NUnit.

- One thing is that to use the built in VS tools you will need to have the Professional SKU or better.