# Recommended unit testing tool to test web services, api calls and sql calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

We are building a new product and we are in phase 0. I was given a task to decide which unit testing tool should be used. I have worked with Rhino mocks, NuNit and testdriven.net in the past and I liked all of them.

I would like to know their pros and cons which could help me in deciding which one to choose.

Comment: please be more specific about what you actually need in your project.

Comment: I will suggest you to expose your application to an extent you can, then only one can suggest you a appropriate testing tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have mentioned Rhino Mocks, NUnit and TestDriven. I would not compare these against one another. However you can  compare each of these with its counterparts.

Here is a start! - I tried to include links for comparisons

**Unit testing Frameworks**

- NUnit
- MsTest
- MBUnit
- xUnit

[NUnit vs. MbUnit vs. MSTest vs. xUnit.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net)

I slightly prefer NUnit, seems to be one of the most used, and it's extremely easy to use. But I would not mind the others.

**Style of testing**

I guess this would effect my testing choice the most.
Unit testing can be done using AAA (Arrange Action Assert) or BDD (Behaviour Driven Development).

I find BDD is really helpful with Domain Driven Design, as it tests the uses stories and puts the domain as a subject under test.

For AAA you can just use the Unit Frameworks.

BDD Frameworks

- [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/)
- [StoryQ](https://launchpad.net/storyq)
- [Simple.Testing](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/Simple.Testing)
- [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications)

Tdd vs Bdd (compare of the approach) 
 http://lostechies.com/seanchambers/2008/12/07/starting-with-bdd-vs-starting-with-tdd/

**Mocks**

Look for a syntax you like for setting up mocks. There are so many in the .NET space.

- Rhino Mocks
- Moq
- NMock
- TypeMock (use if you want to mock out concrete types, but not free)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use

**VS plugins**

Again, whatever makes you feel better

- TestDriven.NET
- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) - I like this (use with PartCover)
- VS (test window)

**Code Coverage**

You did not mention this, however you have to be able to justify code which is written.

- [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/)
- [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/index.html?topDC)
- [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/)
- VS (code coverage)

http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2010/07/16/dotcover---a-new-kid-on-the-development-block.aspx

Edit

**Testing Web Services**

- [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-soap-services.html)

**Database Testing**

- [Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) - if you are using an orm (NHibernate for example), as the sql can slightly change from your sql vendor
- [NDbUnit](http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) - if your are using SP's, ORM or hand cranked SQL

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Since all unit-testing frameworks (at least the ones I know) are based on very similar principles, I think which one to use is mainly a matter of taste. [Here's a table comparing the usage details of various common frameworks in the .net world.](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=xunit)

If you want to employ more of a BDD style, I'd recommend looking at SpecFlow or Machine.Specifications (MSpec). Though both require a xUnit-based unit-testing framework underneath.

As a test runner I use testdriven.net myself, but this is a matter of taste as well. If you're using something like ReSharper or DevExpress CodeRush (you use such a tool, right?) you can use their test runners respectively. (Even though I personally don't like DevExpress' test runner at all.)

The same goes with the mocking framework. Use what you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a mocking frameworks comparaison that might help you to chose another one :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use