# VS 11 Unit Testing Frameworks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, visual-studio-2012, xunit.net

We have started working on VS11 projects involving a DDD - Agile - TDD approach.

I'm using VS 11 Beta and I'm very impressed by the new Unit Tests features that includes the possibility to use 3rd party frameworks (xUnit , NUnit...).

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find out any post/article about a fair comparison between these different frameworks and the new features each one provides in the new IDE.

Which one is suitable for this kind of approach with an intensive and huge projects ?

Thanks for you support.

Melek

Comment: You also find a pretty massive thread on the same topic here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261139/nunit-vs-mbunit-vs-mstest-vs-xunit-net

Comment: This feature you describe was added with Visual Studio 2010 not Visual Studio 2011

Comment: @Ramhound You sure? VS2010 just supports integrated MSTest running

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not constructive for Stack Overflow. If you have some specific features you require, you may have better luck in asking related to them, but a general "which is the best framework" is not suited for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[xUnit codeplex page](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons) has nice comparison of unit-test frameworks in general.